# Using font-variant: small-caps with font (latin extended) on safari

Tags: ios, css, safari

I decided to use `font-variant: small-caps` for my `h1` with font from google fonts ( Roboto Condensed - with **latin extended characters**)

On every browser it renders properly but not on Safari ( tested on macOS Sierra 10.1 )

`font-variant: small-caps` works as well on Safari but not with lating extended charactes. Then it just going creazy. Instead of showing "Bądźmy w kontakcie" it shows "A aa w kontakcie" or it swaps ę to some bolder ę.

How to make it work ?

Comment: Stumbled upon this issue today, too. No time to test thoroughly. From what I saw, this also affects Roboto regular. I see this problem on iPhone 5c, iPhone6 and MacOS Safari. Looks like small-caps are not safe to use on the web atm.

Comment: The question is, is it caused by specific font or it is caused by the way how font is attached

Answer (score 0):

It seems that fonts embeded from google fonts doesnt work for what I need. Maybe if I would attach my fonts diffrently it could work....

Anyway I decided to delete `font-variant` and I used `text-transformation: uppercase` and I changed `font-size` to smaller value and I have same effect that I wanted to produce.